# Coupled partial differential and integro-differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, integral-operators

I have derived two equations of the following type
$$
\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial x}=a\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial t}-b\dfrac{\partial^3 B}{\partial x^2 \partial t}$$
and
$$
\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial x}=\int _0^l e^{-\lambda|x-x'|}\dfrac{\partial A(x')}{\partial t} dx'$$
Where $A$ and $B$ are functions of $x$ and $t$, $x$ and $x'$ are any point between $0$ and $l$ and $a, b, \lambda$ are constants.
Is it possible to transform these two equations into a single partial differential equation for $B$?

Comment: you will need information on $\partial A/\partial t$ to proceed.

Comment: $A$ is a function of $x$ and $t$. As a first approximation, $A$ can be assumed to a sinusoidal function in both space and time $$A=A_0e^{jwt}e^{jax}$$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, from second equation one can obtain $\dfrac{\partial^3 B}{\partial x^3}=\lambda^2\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial x}-2\lambda \dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t}$ and solve for $ \dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t}$ in terms of $B$, then differentiate first equation wrt to $t$ and substitute $ \dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t}$.

Comment: can you please write the detailed step for first equation ?..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to elaborate on Nemo's comment. You first need to note that $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{|x|} = 2\delta_0(x)\cdot e^{|x|} + e^{|x|}$ in the sense of distributions, where $\delta_0(x)$ represents the dirac delta function at $0$. This follows from a simple computation and noting that $\frac{d}{dx}\mathrm{sign}(x) = 2\delta_0(x)$.

Using the above fact, we have that 
$$\frac{\partial^3 B}{\partial x^3} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\int_0^l e^{-\lambda|x-x'|}\frac{\partial A(x')}{\partial t} dx'$$
If we commute the integral with the derivative, we get that 
$$ 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^3 B}{\partial x^3} &= \int_0^l \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}e^{-\lambda|x-x'|}\right)\frac{\partial A(x')}{\partial t} dx' \\
&= \int_0^l \left(-2\lambda \delta_0(|x-x'|)e^{-\lambda|x-x'|} + \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda|x-x'|}\right)  \frac{\partial A(x')}{\partial t} dx' \\
&= -2\lambda \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} + \lambda^2 \frac{\partial B}{\partial x} 
\end{align}
$$

Solving this, we get that 
$$ \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{2\lambda}\left(\lambda^2 \frac{\partial B}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial^3 B}{\partial x^3} \right) $$
Differenting the above equation with respect to $x$ and the first equation with respect to $t$ and setting the two equal to each other, we get 
$$ 
\frac{1}{2\lambda}\left(\lambda^2 \frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^4 B}{\partial x^4} \right) = a \frac{\partial^2 B}{\partial t^2} - b \frac{\partial^4 B}{\partial x^2 \partial t^2}
$$

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Just a remark: because of the limits in the definite integral, the formula you derived for $\partial A(t,x)\partial x$ is valid only for $0\le x \le l$. Outside that interval, if $B(t,x)$ is defined there, you must replace $\partial A(t,x)\partial x$ in that formula by $0$.